# Error when installing pgadmin4 on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, pgadmin

To install pgadmin4 on Raspberry Pi, I ran it by referring to the following document.
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/

But, I am getting error.

I tried like this:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/pgadmin
$ sudo mkdir /var/log/pgadmin
$ sudo chown $USER /var/lib/pgadmin
$ sudo chown $USER /var/log/pgadmin
$ python3 -m venv pgadmin4
$ source pgadmin4/bin/activate
(pgadmin4) $ pip install pgadmin4
```

But, I am getting the following error.

```
(pgadmin4) $ pip install pgadmin4
```

[pgadmin4 install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVH8F.png)

So I tried to install Rust as follows, but I got an error:

```
(pgadmin4) $ pip install Rust
```

[Rust install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKkq.png)

How can I install pgadmin4 on Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error message from the command
`(pgadmin4) $ pip install pgadmin4` because you are using an outdated version of pip, try upgrading your pip by running the command:

`pip install --upgrade pip` in the virtual environment, Then retry

`(pgadmin4) $ pip install pgadmin4`

Comment: I already tried it. But the same error occurs.